# How to make my flex children fit into two rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a total of 8 images that I need to split up into 2 rows. These are under the `.card` group. They have to have equal spacing and alignment with the top corners. I am having some trouble setting this up with flex commands.

```
.cards {
    display: flex;
}

.card {
    width: 24%;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 2em; 
    padding: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you post what html you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-wrap;
}

.card {
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 2em; 
    padding: 0;
    flex: 1 1 24%; /* Assume there are some margins */
}
```